# JS Recursion Error - RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, recursion

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
I am having trouble with this block of recursion, and
I am inexperienced with this concept. below is some sample code and
the two functions that are exceeding the max stack call size.

```
validMove(player, dr, dc, r, c, tempBoard) {
    let opposite;
    if (player == 1) {
        opposite = 2;
    } else if (player == 2) {
        opposite = 1;
    } else {
        //console.log('color error: ' + player);
        return false;
    }

    if (r + dr < 0 || r + dr > 7) {
        return false;
    }
    if (c + dc < 0 || c + dc > 7) {
        return false;
    }
    if (tempBoard[r + dr][c + dc].state != opposite) {
        return false;
    }
    if (r + dr + dr < 0 || r + dr + dr > 7) {
        return false;
    }
    if (c + dc + dc < 0 || c + dc + dc > 7) {
        return false;
    }
    return this.checkLineMatch(player, dr, dc, r + dr + dr, c + dc + dc, tempBoard);
}

checkLineMatch(player, dr, dc, r, c, tempBoard) {
    if (tempBoard[r][c].state == player) {
        return true;
    }
    if (tempBoard[r][c].state == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    if (r + dr < 0 || r + dr > 7) {
        return false;
    }
    if (c + dc < 0 || c + dc > 7) {
        return false;
    }
    return this.checkLineMatch(player, dr, dc, r + dr, c + dr, tempBoard);
}
```

Comment: Some condition before recursion is probably wrong. Console.log each case and limit recursion upon reaching some number to make console readable. You can also trace execution in browser's dev tools and check var values each step..

Comment: Can you provide a `data set` to test your functions? Also, how do you invoke it?